# Changing Tab Content Depending on Which Element of the Spinner is Selected

Tags: android, eclipse, onclick, spinner

I am trying to make a tab-based application that is a school scheduling app.

I am using a tabhost in activitiy_main.xml to use all of the data (setting the tab names, elements, etc.).

What I want to do is have a spinner (located in tab3 of my tabhost) dictate what options are shown below it.

I have multiple options that I want to show.

Here is tab3's XML layout located in my activity_main_xml :

`

```
      <TextView
          android:id="@+id/labelAdd"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="@string/add"
          android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

      <Spinner
          android:id="@+id/addDropDown"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:entries="@array/type_array" />

      <Button
          android:id="@+id/StartTimeButton"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="@string/addStartTime" />

      <TextView
          android:id="@+id/startTimeLabel"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="@string/addStartTime" />

      <TimePicker
          android:id="@+id/startTimePicker"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

      <TextView
          android:id="@+id/endTimeLabel"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="@string/addEndTime" />

      <TimePicker
          android:id="@+id/endTimePicker"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

      <TextView
          android:id="@+id/addRepeatQ"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="@string/addRepeatQ" />

      <RadioGroup
          android:id="@+id/repeatRadioGroup"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

          <RadioButton
              android:id="@+id/addRepeatN"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:checked="true"
              android:text="@string/addRepeatN" />

          <RadioButton
              android:id="@+id/addRepeatY"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:text="@string/addRepeatY" />
      </RadioGroup>

      <Button
          android:id="@+id/addNextButton"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="@string/addNext" />

  </LinearLayout>`
```

I want to make certain items, specifically the startTimeLabel, StartTimeButton, endTimeLabel, endTimeButton ONLY display when a certain element of my spinner is selected (in this case, the item selected would be titled "class").

Any help for how to start structuring my .java? I am new to Android programming but have experience in java, html, php, sql and Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

```
urSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int arg2, long arg3) 
        {
            //write your code here what you want
                      change visibility of your Views(buttons,textviews) etc

        }

        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {


        }
    });
```

if u get the idea pls mrkd it as answer